# How can I display text from a page in the radrails console?

Tags: ruby, console, report, watir

I use radrails IDE for running watir tests.

I have opened a page with information about an error and now I want show the text of this page in the console. How can i do this?

Here is my code:

```
ie4=Watir::IE.attach(:title, "My page")
ie4.send_keys [:control, "a"]
ie4.send_keys [:control, "c"] 
puts (ie4.send_keys [:control, "v"])
```

This code gives `1` and not the error text. Also can someone suggest a good way to make html test reports in watir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to copy all text of the page?

You could just do:

```
ie4=Watir::IE.attach(:title, "My page")
puts ie4.text
```